# Why is my pry-byebug package giving so much output when a command executes some error?

Tags: ruby, pry, byebug

I had recently installed the gem `pry-byebug`, when I noticed it required at least Ruby version 2.4 in order to function. So I updated my Ruby using `rvm`, and then installed the gems `pry` and `pry-byebug`. Everything was working just fine. I started writing some code and setting some breakpoints with `binding.pry`.

But now when I am debugging, I have to deal with a huge amount of output from what ostensibly is the code base of `pry-byebug`, and this has made my debugging process quite more obfuscated, since I must shift through all this redundant output in order to pinpoint where my problem is.

As an example, let us say I set a `binding.pry` breakpoint in a part of the code where I have instantiated some objects.

```
casting1= {'movie_name'=> 'The Room, 'star_name'=> 'Tommy Wiseau', 'star_fee'=>20000}
casting2= {'movie_name'=> 'Come and See', 'star_name'=> 'Aleksei Kravchenko', 'star_fee'=>1000}
casting_object1= Casting.new(casting1)
casting_object2= Casting.new(casting2)

binding.pry()
```

Let's assume that I start looking at the objects `casting_object1` and `casting_object2` in order to figure out whether their methods have been properly written, and that I accidentally type in some minor error like calling an object/function that does not exist. I get this kind of output:

```
[1] pry(main)> casting_object1
[2] pry(main)> casting_object5

Traceback (most recent call last):
        27: from console.rb:64:in `<main>'
        26: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'
        25: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:65:in `at_line'
        24: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:113:in `resume_pry'
        23: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `run'
        22: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `catch'
        21: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block in run'
        20: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:94:in `allowing_other_threads'
        19: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        18: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:117:in `block in resume_pry'
        17: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
        16: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
        15: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
        14: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in `with_ownership'
        13: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in `__with_ownership'
        12: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
        11: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
        10: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
         9: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:77:in `block in repl'
         8: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:272:in `eval'
         7: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:272:in `catch'
         6: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:273:in `block in eval'
         5: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:273:in `catch'
         4: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in eval'
         3: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:355:in `handle_line'
         2: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:387:in `evaluate_ruby'
         1: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:387:in `eval'
(pry):3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `casting' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  casting_object2
               casting_object1
        27: from console.rb:64:in `<main>'
        26: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'
        25: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:65:in `at_line'
        24: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:113:in `resume_pry'
        23: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `run'
        22: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `catch'
        21: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block in run'
        20: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:94:in `allowing_other_threads'
        19: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        18: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:117:in `block in resume_pry'
        17: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
        16: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
        15: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
        14: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in `with_ownership'
        13: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in `__with_ownership'
        12: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
        11: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
        10: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
         9: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:77:in `block in repl'
         8: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:272:in `eval'
         7: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:272:in `catch'
         6: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:273:in `block in eval'
         5: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:273:in `catch'
         4: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in eval'
         3: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:349:in `handle_line'
         2: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:356:in `rescue in handle_line'
         1: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/exceptions.rb:16:in `==='
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/exceptions.rb:28:in `===': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        12: from console.rb:64:in `<main>'
        11: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'
        10: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:65:in `at_line'
         9: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:113:in `resume_pry'
         8: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `run'
         7: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:29:in `catch'
         6: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block in run'
         5: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/byebug-11.1.1/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:94:in `allowing_other_threads'
         4: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in run'
         3: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:117:in `block in resume_pry'
         2: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
         1: from /Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:201:in `rescue in start'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/exceptions.rb:28:in `===': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

No matter what kind of error is evoked, I consistently get this kind of output that appears to be referring to code in the code base of the `pry` or `pry-byebug` gem. While this is not a major problem (since I can still set breakpoints and manipulate objects in pry), there is so much superfluous output that the process of pinpointing bugs becomes not particularly easy or clear-cut, especially in the terminal setting. I have tried to amend this problem myself by uninstalling and reinstalling the gems `pry` and `pry-byebug`, and have also tried to install previous versions of `pry` and `pry-byebug` in order for it to work. I have tried to googling this issue, but I sadly am not familiar enough with the terminology in order to pinpoint what the matter actually is.

Ever since I updated my Ruby with rvm, this problem has been occurring. I would prefer not to go back to an older version of Ruby since some of the gems I use in my code require the latest version. Can anybody give me any feedback to explain why this is happening, and possibly, how I can solve it? I am using macOS Mojave v10.14.6, and utilizing Ruby v2.7.0-preview1

**UPDATE**

So I went to the github repository of `pry-byebug` and I found that some other users encountered the same problem as me.

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/138

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/110

Sadly, both these issues remain unresolved, but one user did say there was a way to "monkey patch" the problem using the function `print_traceback`. After locating the `print_traceback` function in the `where.rb` file of the `bye-bug` gem, I tried to implement this monkey patch. Sadly it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I recently just used rvm to download and set my default version of Ruby to 2.6.5. The verbose output has now ceased entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It's a full backtrace of not only the error but the code that caught the error. Just follow the trace. If you don't like the verbose output then send a PR, don't monkey patch. If the gem gets updated then your patch is useless if you want to stay updated.

Comment: I am aware that the output is a full backtrace. But I really don't think that I can send a pull request to a popular Ruby gem in order for them to change the verbosity of their output. I really just want to see what settings on my part I can modify in order to reduce said verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can downgrade to pry-byebug-3.6.0 and it may solve the issue.
I am using 3.6.0 and no problem with printing the full backtrace.

Comment: I have tried to downgrade to different versions of pry-byebug, pry, and also byebug itself, and have found that the output remains consistently verbose.